# A question in Complex Analysis $\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos x +r^2)\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, harmonic-functions

My problem is to integrate this expression: 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos x +r^2)dx.$$
where $r$ is any constant in $[0,1]$.

I know the answer is zero. Can you explain you idea to me or just prove that?
Maybe you will use the "Cauchy integral theorem ".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing $\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1-2a\cos x+a^2\right) \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650513/computing-int-0-pi-ln-left1-2a-cos-xa2-right-dx) (which contains an answer using complex analysis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** I have proved a little more. Namely, this integral is $0$ for $| r|\leq 1$, and $4\pi\log|r|$ for $|r|\geq 1$.

1) If $r=0$, this is $0$.

2) Now assume $0< r\leq 1$. We have
$$
1-2r\cos x+r^2=(1-re^{ix})(1-re^{-ix})=|1-re^{ix}|^2.
$$
Hence the integral can be written
$$
2\int_0^{2\pi}\log |1-re^{ix}|dx=4\pi\cdot \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\log |1-re^{ix}|dx=
\frac{2}{i}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{\log|1-z|}{z}dz.
$$

where $\gamma_r(x)=re^{ix}$ over $[0,2\pi]$, i.e. $\gamma_r$ is the circle of radius $r$ centered at $0$.

**Shortcut**: as pointed out by robjohn, $\log|1-z|=\mbox{Re}\;\log(1-z)$, so we can conclude by Cauchy's integral formula. I'll leave my harmonic argument below.

[Recall that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183622/is-ln-f-harmonic) if $f$ is holomorphic, then $\log|f|$ is **harmonic** on its domain. So $$g:z\longmapsto \log|1-z|$$ is harmonic on the open unit disk $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\;;\;|z|<1\}$.

If $0<r<1$, then the circle $\gamma_r$ is contained in $D$ and contains $0$, so 
$$
0=g(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}g(re^{ix})dx=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\log |1-re^{ix}|dx
$$
by the **mean value property** of harmonic functions.

3) For $r=1$ now. Fix $x$ and study the variations of $r\longmapsto \log(1-2r\cos x+r^2)$ on $[0,1]$. If $\cos x\leq 0$, this is increasing and nonnegative, so $|\log(1-2r\cos x+r^2)|\leq \log(1-2\cos x+1)$. And if $\cos x\geq 0$, it is nonpositive with a minimum at $r=\cos x$, so $|\log(1-2r\cos x+r^2)|\leq| \log(1-2\cos^2 x+\cos^2 x)|=| \log(\sin^2 x)|$. In any case, we see  that the integrand is uniformly bounded by an integrable function. It follows that 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2\cos x+1)dx=\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^-} \int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos x+r^2)dx=0
$$
by **Lebesgue dominated convergence**.

So these integrals are $0$ for every $0\leq r\leq 1$.

4) By change of variable and periodicity, we get $0$ for $-1\leq r\leq 1$.

5) Finally, for $|r|>1$, we get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos x+r^2)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(r^2\left(\frac{1}{r^2}-2\frac{1}{r}\cos x+1\right)\right)dx
$$
$$
=\int_0^{2\pi}\log r^2dx+ \int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{1}{r^2}-2\frac{1}{r}\cos x+1\right)dx=4\pi \log |r|+0.
$$

Comment: Thank U very much!and I've mistaken its range (0,1) for [0,1].Nevertheless,I'll be curious about whether this still holds when r=1.

Comment: one more question,does this proof hold if x∈[0,π]?I had typed this,but it turned out to be [0,2π],and maybe it's the system who changed my input...= =

Comment: well,I think its integration on [0,π] equals that on [π,2π],if I change the variant x into -x,then add 2π onto the integral interval.am I right?

Comment: @sopin The change of variable $u=\pi+x$ is what you want. ANd you're right, then it works. So the integral over $[0,\pi]$ is half the integral over $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thank you again for bothering to answer my question patiently.

Comment: @sopin You're welcome. No problem! Questions are meant to be asked. And hopefully answered.

Answer (score 10):

[Copying from my blog](http://sivaramambikasaran.blogspot.com/2013/04/displaystyle-int0pi-ln-1-2a-cosx-a2-dx.html).

Let $$I(a) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left(1-2a \cos(x) + a^2\right) dx$$ Some preliminary results on $I(a)$. Note that we have $$I(a) = \underbrace{\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left(1+2a \cos(x) + a^2\right) dx}_{\spadesuit} = \overbrace{\dfrac12 \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(1-2a \cos(x) + a^2\right) dx}^{\clubsuit}$$ $(\spadesuit)$ can be seen by replacing $x \mapsto \pi-x$ and $(\clubsuit)$ can be obtained by splitting the integral from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\pi$ to $2 \pi$ and replacing $x$ by $\pi+x$ in the second integral.
Now let us move on to our computation of $I(a)$.
\begin{align}
I(a^2) & = \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left(1-2a^2 \cos(x) + a^4\right) dx = \dfrac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(1-2a^2 \cos(x) + a^4\right) dx\\
& = \dfrac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left((1+a^2)^2-2a^2(1+ \cos(x))\right) dx = \dfrac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left((1+a^2)^2-4a^2 \cos^2(x/2)\right) dx\\
& = \dfrac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(1+a^2-2a \cos(x/2)\right) dx + \dfrac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(1+a^2+2a \cos(x/2)\right) dx
\end{align}
Now replace $x/2=t$ in both integrals above to get
\begin{align}
I(a^2) & = \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left(1+a^2-2a \cos(t)\right) dt + \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left(1+a^2+2a \cos(t)\right) dt = 2I(a)
\end{align}
Now for $a \in [0,1)$, this gives us that $I(a) = 0$. This is because we have $I(0) = 0$ and $$I(a) = \dfrac{I(a^{2^n})}{2^n}$$ Now let $n \to \infty$ and use continuity to conclude that $I(a) = 0$ for $a \in [0,1)$. Now lets get back to our original problem. Consider $a>1$. We have
\begin{align*}
I(1/a) & = \int_0^{\pi} \ln \left(1-\dfrac2{a} \cos(x) + \dfrac1{a^2}\right)dx\\
& = \int_0^{\pi} \ln(1-2a \cos(x) + a^2) dx - 2\int_0^{\pi} \ln(a)dx\\
& = I(a) - 2 \pi \ln(a)\\
& = 0  \tag{Since $1/a < 1$, we have $I(1/a) = 0$}
\end{align*}
Hence, we get that
$$I(a) = \begin{cases} 2 \pi \ln(a) & a \geq 1 \\ 0 & a \in [0,1] \end{cases}$$

Comment: I would have never thought of doing it like this, funny...+1.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer.It is good to find many different ways of solving the same question.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos(x)+r^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\,\mathrm{Re}\left(\oint_\gamma\log(1-z)\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where the contour of integration is $\gamma(x)=re^{ix}$.

Since there is no singularity inside the contour, the integral is $0$.

Comment: Nice to invoke the (obvious) harmonic conjugate, +1. As lots of people seem to like holomorphic functions better than harmonic ones...Note this is true for $0<r<1$ only.

Comment: well,seems great...but can you explain further why the equation holds?

Comment: my book writes:log(z)=log|z|+iargz,with 0<argz<2π.

Comment: @sopin Yes, sorry, typo. So you get the formula when you take the real part.

Comment: @julien oh,I see.thank you!and thank robjohn!

Answer (score 1):

An idea: putting

$$z:=re^{ix}:=r\cos x+i\,r\sin x\;,\;\;r,x\in\Bbb R\implies dz=rie^{ix}dx\;,\;\; 1-2r\cos x+r^2=|z-1|^2$$

so by an extension to [Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) from the MVHF (see Note and comments below) we get
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos x+r^2)dx=\frac{2}{i}\int\limits_{S^1}\frac{\log|z-1|}{z}dz=4\pi\left(\log|z-1|\right)_{z=0}=0$$

**Note:** In fact the result follows at once from the Mean Value Property for Harmonic Functions (see comments below and Julien's answer), which can be seen as a "special" kind of extension or, perhaps more accurate, special case of the CIF. Follow the links below and above

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula is for holomorphic functions. This one is harmonic. Also, this only works for $0<r<1$. And finally, this formula is exactly the one I used. So we agree on this.

Comment: First, yes: this only works for $\,0\le r<1\,$ as we don't want the logarithm to go around (the/a) point where its argument vanishes. Second, because the same reason, I think this function is holomorphic in the domain limited by the unit circle as we'll always be away from the problematic point $\,z=1\,$ and thus CIF is appliable...unless I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: See my answer. We can compute this for every $r$, actually. The intergral always converges. Now $\log|z-1|$ is real-valued, harmonic, not holomorphic. The only real-valued holomorphic functions are constant.

Comment: See the [open mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) to see why real valued holomorphic implies constant. Although with such a strong assumption as real-valued, it can be done with more elementary tools.

Comment: Oh, I know we can compute for every $\,r\,$ yet we'll have to add multiples of $\,2\pi\,$ to the argument and/or choose branch cuts and it all becomes another mess.

Comment: It is definitely not a big mess...and it does not require to choose branch cuts. Take a look at my answer. And you should remove your Cauchy' integral formula argument, if I may insist. This function is not holomorphic, as you can see from my previous comments. Finally, note that we are only using the real log here.

Comment: I see your point, yet I wonder whether in cases like this one CIF can be applied by means of some extension...?

Comment: Yes. It is called the mean value property of harmonic functions. Which is actually the definition of harmonicity in many places.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Look at http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-21/3/210.extract for some kind of extension to harmonic functions. I remember having seen some stuff like this some decades ago, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not "some kind of extension". The mean value property defines harmonic functions. For holomrphic functions, it "becomes" Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Ok, so lemme see if I get it: the integral equals zero since, by the MV property for harmonic functions it equals a multiple of its value at the center of the uncit circle...Well, that's even nicer and simpler!

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Damn, I need to go back over this stuff again! Thanks @julien, I've learned (re-learned? It's the same, almost) something today.

Comment: You're most welcome. About your edit: CIF is the special case. Not the other way around.