# The function $f(x)=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(x^2-2x\cos t+1\right)\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals, logarithms

Consider the function $f$ defined by
$$f(x)=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(x^2-2x\cos t+1\right) \,dt.$$

I tried calculating values of this function using Wolfram Alpha and I observed that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. How can we prove this fact?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352046/42969

Comment: @MartinR thanks I searched math.stack before posting but I didn't found something similar. Can I ask how did you found it. Thanks again!!

Comment: With [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(x)%3D%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cln%5Cleft(x%5E2-2x%5Ccos%20t%2B1%5Cright)dt%24&p=1) – See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange on Meta.

Comment: @MartinR thanks a lot. That really helps!!!